# Static IP for Nodejs on Amazon

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, socket.io, static-ip-address

I have ubuntu instance running on my `Amazon ec2`. Which has `MAMP` installed which I can access through my `Static IP` and every thing works fine. Now I installed node.js in the instance where as it's running in `localhost`. But when I am trying to give my static IP

> var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000,"54.XXX.XXX.XXX")

it's not working. I tried many option for configuring this but nothing seems to work out.

Answer (score 0):

Port 3000 is most likely blocked on that IP and you will have to open it explicitly in AWS control panel.

Comment: I did that it's still not working. FYI it's not working curl.